# Kohana3: Absolute path to a file

Tags: php, file, path, kohana, kohana-3

Say I have a file in my kohana 3 website called `assets/somefile.jpg`. I can get the url to that file by doing

```
 echo Url::site('assets/somefile.jpg'); // /kohana/assets/somefile.jpg
```

Is there a way I can get the absolute path to that file? Like if I want to `fopen` it or get the size of the file or something like that.

In other words, I would like to get something like `/var/www/kohana/assets/somefile.jpg` or `W:\www\kohana\assets\somefile.jpg` or whatever is the absolute path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want:

```
DOCROOT.'assets/somefile.jpg'
```

Comment: Is that defined in the bootstrap or something? Or? Can't remember to have seen that constant anywhere...

Comment: (Will check it out first thing when I get to my computer though)

Comment: It's in your index.php. You can also use things like APPPATH, SYSTPATH and MODPATH.

Comment: Ah, ok. Will def check that out then! :D

Comment: Sorry, it should say SYSPATH above, not SYSTPATH.

Comment: @zombor: Tested it out now, and DOCROOT seems to have done the trick. Since my code might run on windows sometimes, I use this little snippet: `$absolute = DOCROOT.str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $url)`, where `$url` might for example be `assets/somefile.jpg`. Seems to work :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with Kohana but isn't that the job of [Kohana::find_file](http://api.kohanaphp.com/class_kohana.html#75fc3a1564d7402eb50fafcf04be0634)?

> Finds the path of a file by directory, filename, and extension. If no extension is given, the default EXT extension will be used.
>
> When searching the "config" or "i18n" directory, an array of files will be returned. These files will return arrays which must be merged together.

Comment: Does that exist in Kohana 3 though? Can't find it in the api there at least: http://v3.kohanaphp.com/guide/api

Comment: @Svish it should be there: http://v3.kohanaphp.com/guide/api/Kohana (search for find_file)

Comment: @Pekka: Aaah. Tried to search for it in the overview there. Didn't think about going in to the Kohana part there. Will try that the next time I am looking for something! Thanks! Will try out that function when I get to my workstation :)

Comment: Find file is for assets in the cascading filesystem (classes, views, etc). The file you are trying to find doesn't really apply to this.

Comment: @zombor: So in other words files that are under the `application` folder? If so, is there an alternative? Or is it the `DOCROOT` constant that someone else here mentioned I have to use?

Comment: Well, things that are in the application, modules, or system folder. The point of find_file() is to merge the filesystem and return the proper file. If you are just looking for an asset in your website like an image, this is usually not what find_file() is used for.

When I said use DOCROOT, I was assuming that your file URI was something like http://localhost/assets/somefile.jpg and not a file in your kohana filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Try echo realpath('assets/somefile.jpg').

Comment: That will work only if his PHP script happens to be in the project's root directory.

Comment: Yeah, I need to use it in a class and I don't really have a clue where it will be launched from.